# displaying highlighted text android

Tags: android, text, highlight, tostring

I want that my highlighted text is being displayed as the text on the button.

```
 EditText et;
Button button;
String test;
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    et    =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
    int startSelection=et.getSelectionStart();
    int endSelection=et.getSelectionEnd();

    test = et.getText().toString().substring(startSelection, endSelection);
    button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    button.setText(test);
                }
            });
```

I don't get why it doesn't work, I thought getseltectionstart and end is transferring my text into a string and then displays it on the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html#getSelectionStart(java.lang.CharSequence)

> public static final int getSelectionStart (CharSequence text)
>
> Added in API level 1 Return the offset of the selection anchor or
>   cursor, or -1 if there is no selection or cursor.

So as soon as you instantiate your items, you call getSelectionStart() and getSelectionEnd(), which both return -1 (as you haven't selected anything).

Comment: ok, and how am I going to instantiate them after the selection?

Comment: Check for the selection inside the onClick method of the button for example :

Answer (score 0):

```
    button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    int startSelection=et.getSelectionStart();
                    int endSelection=et.getSelectionEnd();
                    test = et.getText().toString().substring(startSelection, endSelection);
                    button.setText(test);
                }
            });

}
```

works, thank you!